# What does full-dimensional mean when speaking about convex cones?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I want to know the exact definition of full-dimensional. And what does "dimension" refer to, is that in the sense of algebraic variety?

I have read several writing announcing that the cone of semi-defined positive matrix is full-dimensional  without giving a clear definition of what dimension mean.

It is written in  [G.Barker and D. Carlson. Cones of diagonally dominant matrices.](http://msp.org/pjm/1975/57-1/pjm-v57-n1-p03-p.pdf) that if C is a cone in a vector space X. C is full if C - C = X

In another [Doctoral report](http://www.lancs.ac.uk/~fairbrot/files/cones.pdf) to demonstrate that $ \mathcal{S}_+^n $ is of full-dimensional, they create  a basis of $ \mathcal{S}^n$ formed of  element of $ \mathcal{S}_+^n $

It gets clearer after this last result, but not fully clear, So thank you for more clarification.

Comment: "Full-dimensional" means something whose dimension is the same as that of the space it is embedded in. This applies not only to cones but to arbitrary regions. For example, in $\mathbb R^3$, a ball is full-dimensional, but a disk lying in the $xy$-plane is not full-dimensional. Do you want a proof that for cones the two definitions in the question are equivalent to this notion?

Comment: just the notion of dimension of a non vector space was not clear. but @orangeskid gave me a very clear clarification. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the cone generates the vector space, equivalently, it contains a basis of the vector space. Since the cone is invariant under addition and multiplications by scalars from $[0, \infty)$ this is equivalent to $C - C = \text{ full space}$

For example, the cone of positive semi-definite matrices generates the space of symmetric matrices since every to  symmetric matrix we can add a positive multiple of the identity and obtain a positive matrix, so the initial matrix is a difference of two positive semi-definite matrix.

A cone $C$ is not an algebraic variety. However, the algebraic closure of $C$ will be a linear subspace, in fact $C-C$. So in some sense it is the algebraic dimension, in the sense of maximal number of polynomial functions on $C$ that are algebraically independent.